What is the relationship between pressure, flow, and resistance?
I know that blood flow is governed by the following equation:
$$Q=\frac{ΔP}{R}$$
This should mean that if the flow is constant then the difference in pressure increases when resistance increases.
But I read that in vessel with the largest portion of the resistance have the greatest decrease in pressure. How is that possible?

You need to give your source. Were they assuming constant $Q$?

I read it in a physiology textbook by Linda S. Costanzo on page 124 where she says:"Although total flow is constant at each level in the series (series of resistance), the pressure decreases progressively as blood flows through each sequential component (remember Q=ΔP/R). The greatest decrease in pressure occurs in the arterioles because they contribute the largest portion of the resistance." @BioPhysicist

What you read agrees exactly with your assertion that "the difference in pressure increases when resistance increases". I,E. "the largest portion of resistance"= increased resistance compared with another vessel, and; "greatest decrease in pressure" = increased difference in pressure. Note that a large decrease in pressure is equivalent to a large ΔP, just as would be a large increase in pressure (measured from the other end of the vessel).

Can you please tell me why decrease in pressure is equivalent to a large ΔP? @Penguino

ΔP = P1-P2. If P1 is measured 'upstream' and P2 is measured 'downstream' then ΔP will be a positive number. And if "The greatest decrease in pressure occurs in the arterioles" then P2 will be small relative to P1 in arterioles i.e. pressure has decreased significantly. Thus P1-P2 will eb a big number. I have no idea what units blood pressure is measured in but if, for example, one vessed showed a drop from 120 to 110 then ΔP=120-110=10, and a second drop showed a greater decrease from 120 to 90, then ΔP=120-90=30, i.e. a greater decrease results in a bigger ΔP.

Just to make sure I got that right, you assigned the pressure in arterioles by P2. Is that correct?@Penguino

@Penguino That looks like an answer to me

I am assuming that ΔP is the pressure drop between two points in a blood vessel. That is to say: ΔP = P1-P2, where P1 is measured at a first point 'upstream in the flow' and P2 is measured at a second point 'downstream in the flow'. That will result in ΔP being a positive number.
The physiology text you quote states that "The greatest decrease in pressure occurs in the arterioles". If that is the case then, in arterioles, P2 will be smaller (relative to P1) than it would be in other vessels. Thus P1-P2 will be a bigger number when measured along an arteriole than when measured alomg a vessel with a smaller decrease in poressure.
I think that your confusion may be in the wording that a "greater decrease" (in pressure) results in an increased difference in pressure, but in essence it is just simple arithematic. I have no idea what units blood pressure is measured in but imagine two blood vessels. Imagine that the first vessed showed a pressure drop from 120 to 110 (measured upstream and downstream respectively) so ΔP=120-110=10 in teh first vessel, and a second vessel showed a pressure drop from 120 to 90, so ΔP=120-90=30 in the second vessel. So the second vessel, with the largest pressure drop (120->90) has a bigger ΔP than the first vessel.
